# How to know the exact country or province from the longitude and latitude information automatically?

Tags: gps

To be more specific, how to find all of point (from 1,000,000 items) located in England, or located in California?

I need to process over 1,000,000 items, so a offline and automatic way is needed.

The geographical information is like this:
39.2903848   -76.6121893

Is there any database can deal with this?

Comment: Spatial databases like PostGIS, Microsoft SQL Spatial, etc. can handle this. A few questions, though: are you querying a 'places' polygon? That is, with each XY, are you trying to get the name of the polygon at that location? Also: is the XY in two separate fields in your data? Can you convert them to a shapefile and/or a geometry column in a spatial database?

Comment: what software do you have available to you? ArcGIS? QGIS? other?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this would have to be an offline process -- I can do point-to-country_code searches with a mean of 3 microseconds per point (3 seconds total).  A lot of the difficulty comes from one of two major sources:  The resolution of the country boundary data, and the politics involved (there are plenty of disputed boundaries).  There are many databases that can deal with this problem, but you'd need to clarify the required resolution (higher resolution == slower evaluation) and the political authority for the data.

Comment: http://services.gisgraphy.com/public/geocoding.html

Comment: @Mapperz would be interesting to see how to use that site for 1,000,000 geocodes...!

Comment: Have done 4.7 million geocodes on yahoo over 3 years...

Comment: @Mapperz so this is an application that runs on top of Java, Postgres and Postgis?

Comment: Correct http://www.gisgraphy.com/download/index.htm you can run your own.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am a CS student, and not familiar with GIS tools. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download this file which is public and contains the borders of all countries and regions int the world: [thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip)

You could then put it in a geographical database, PostGIS for example would do it, but that is not even necessary. Once you unzip the file, you will find a shapefile (ESRI format), that you can manipulate directly with the library GDAL.

So the best way is probably to install the GDAL library for the language you are using, and then you will be able to manipulate the content of the shapefile, and use it to find the country for each of your points.

For instance, with Python you could do something like that:

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
fn = 'TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'
dataSource = driver.Open(fn, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

myPoint = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
myPoint.SetPoint_2D(0, -76.6121893, 39.2903848)

for feat in layer :
    poly = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    if myPoint.Within(poly) :
        print feat.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks very much. In my Mac, I must release the memory (`code` del poly), otherwise some error happens.
A further question, this database only includes the national data? How can I find the data of states in U.S.?
Thanks very much. at least I can make my own coarse 'poly'.

Comment: You can easily find shapefiles of USA states borders. A quick search gave me [nationalatlas.gov](http://nationalatlas.gov) but I am sure there are many others.